# Show the existence of decreasing set sequence $G_k$ st. $G_1⊇G_2⊇G_3⊇⋯⊇Ω$ and $|⋂G_k |_e=|Ω|_e$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The problem is

> Let $Ω$ be a set in $\Bbb{R}^n$. Show that there exists a decreasing sequence $G_k$ of open sets such that $G_1⊇G_2⊇G_3⊇⋯⊇Ω$ and $|⋂G_k |_e=|Ω|_e$.

where $|Ω|_e$ denotes outer measure.

This claim seems to be a stronger version of a theorem which states

> $∀Ω⊂\Bbb{R}^n$ there exists a $G_δ$ set $H$ st. $Ω⊆H$ and $|Ω|_e=|H|_e$

where a  $G_δ$ set is a countable intersection of open sets. Hope someone can help. Thank you!

---

**The following is my attempt** but now I realize it might be incorrect.
[image]

The statement to prove requires $G_1⊇G_2⊇G_3⊇⋯⊇Ω$, but my construction in the attempt can only support $Ω\subseteq G_1\subseteq G_2 \subseteq G_3 \subseteq...$.

Comment: Why is it stronger than the theorem? What is a $G_\delta$ set if not the intersection of countably many open sets (and therefore the intersection of a decreasing sequence of open sets)? Do you already know the theorem is true?

Comment: In the theorem it states the existence of countable intersection of open sets, in the problem it is to show the existence of countable intersection of decreasing open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\cal A$ is a family of sets closed under finite intersections (e.g. open sets in a topological space). Then any countable intersection of sets in $\cal A$ can be written as a decreasing intersection.

Let $A_n\in\cal A$, define $B_n=\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i$. Then by the closure of $\cal A$ we have that $B_n\in\cal A$ for all $n$. It suffices to show that $\bigcap A_n=\bigcap B_n$. And I will leave this part to you.

From this you can easily deduce the statement from the theorem, recalling that every $G_\delta$ set is the countable intersection of open sets.